# Standard REST de-serialisation fails: Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization

Tags: rest-api, json

Consider the following class:

```
public class Caps {
    public Sett SETTINGS {get;set;}
}
public class Sett {
    public string foo {get;set;}
}
```

When I POST the following JSON:

```
{"SETTINGS":{"foo":"bar"}}
```

To my own REST class:

```
...
@HttpPost
global static void doPost(Caps change) {
}
```

I get 400 Bad Request:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Unexpected parameter encountered during deserialization: SETTINGS at [line:1, column:14]",
    "errorCode": "JSON_PARSER_ERROR"
  }
]
```

However the exact same JSON can be de-serialised as follows:

```
String s = '{"SETTINGS":{"foo":"bar"}}';
Caps c = (Caps)JSON.deserialize(s, Caps.class);
system.debug(c);
```

As a workaround I can do the de-serialisation in my REST class:

```
@HttpPost
global static ZRest.ZRestResponse doPost() {
    String req = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
    Caps change = (Caps)JSON.deserialize(req, Caps.class);
}
```

This works fine and I get 200.

The question is why doesn't the standard REST de-serialisation of parameters work?

PS: I read possible duplicate questions but they only seem to offer a workaround or the same string in a different format (newlines, indents) which doesn't solve my issue at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a consequence of Salesforce's design decision that allows for example this code:

```
@HttpPost
global static void doPost(String x, Integer y) {
}
```

to accept this JSON:

```
{
    "x": "abc",
    "y": 123
}
```

The names and types of the method arguments form part of the JSON structure.

So in your case the following JSON would work:

```
{"change":{"SETTINGS":{"foo":"bar"}}}
```

Comment: Your first sentence seems like it's either ungrammatical or missing a link. Still, +1, this is good to know.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've added a few more words to try to improve.

Comment: Much less confusing for me! I made one more minor tweak, hope you don't mind.

Comment: @AdrianLarson No problem.

Comment: It would be icing on the cake if you can find a supporting documentation link.